# C++ : Is this polymorphism possible?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have those two classes :

```
class Foo
{
    virtual void Bar2();
    void Bar(){Bar2();};
}

class Foo2 : public Foo
{
    void Bar2();
}
```

Will calling the Bar() function in Foo use the Bar2 function from Foo2 or Foo? I would like it to use Foo2's.

Comment: you are calling `Bar()` of which instance? :)

Comment: do you have a compiler?

Comment: This would be ridiculously easy to test on your own... why are you asking us?

Comment: Do you even attempt to answer this question for yourself? Say by printing out some information and running a test case?

Comment: I tested for you - http://ideone.com/8YqdxR

Comment: This is actually a very common idiom.  In most cases, virtual functions should be private, and only called from public non-virtual members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will use the `Bar2` of whatever type that is instantiated, like this:

```
Foo2 f2;
f2.Bar(); // Foo2::Bar2 will be called

Foo f;
f.Bar();  // Foo::Bar2 will be called

Foo *pf = new Foo2;
pf->Bar(); // Foo2::Bar2 will be called
```